# How to have a specific image show up for everyone who comments?

Tags: images, comments, avatar, logo

How can I have an image I created be a avatar for everyone who comments on my wordpress posts?

So it will have my logo or something instead of a blank square?

Thanks!!

Comment: Welcome to [wordpress.se]. What did you try so far?

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter( 'get_avatar' , 'my_custom_avatar' , 1 , 5 );

function my_custom_avatar( $avatar, $id_or_email, $size, $default, $alt ) {
    $user = false;

    if ( is_numeric( $id_or_email ) ) {

        $id = (int) $id_or_email;
        $user = get_user_by( 'id' , $id );

    } elseif ( is_object( $id_or_email ) ) {

        if ( ! empty( $id_or_email->user_id ) ) {
            $id = (int) $id_or_email->user_id;
            $user = get_user_by( 'id' , $id );
        }

    } else {
        $user = get_user_by( 'email', $id_or_email );   
    }

    if ( $user && is_object( $user ) ) {

        if ( $user->data->ID == '1' ) {
            $avatar = 'YOUR_NEW_IMAGE_URL';
            $avatar = "<img alt='{$alt}' src='{$avatar}' class='avatar avatar-{$size} photo' height='{$size}' width='{$size}' />";
        }

    }

    return $avatar;
}
```

enter the new image url and paste this code in functions.php 
Explaination can be found here.
[how to modify avatar](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/get_avatar)

Comment: Please don't link to the explanation, add the explanation **inside** your answer through an [edit]. Your code will mean nothing if that link ever dies. You should just use the link as reference, author credit